# Are the W3C geolocation API accuracy parameter in diameter or radius of your position?

Tags: api, geolocation

Maybe i got my head around this wrong, after stfw i could not find any info on this. When the geolocation api returns your position with latitute, longitude and accuracy (p.coords.accuracy), does the accuracy parameter return diameter or radius of your position? For instance, if accuracy of my position is 24 meters, does that mean i could be standing anywhere within a radius of 24 meters of my position, or within 12 meters radius of my position (that would give a 24 meters diameter, me being in the middle of the circle of accuracy)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It would be the radius.  So if the accuracy is 24, then the true position is within 24 meters, which would mean it would lie within a circle with radius 24 around the coordinate.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?